# IIF query, display no data if false ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a query that displays no data if false. Right now I have my query and the false portion of my IIF query is "". That is displaying an empty box for that field. I want my query to show no box at all. Can I do that with an IIF statement? Maybe I need a WHERE clause? SQL statement is below:

```
SELECT
IIF(s.[Destroyed(yes/no)] = "no", s.Station_ID, "") AS Active_Stations, p.Days_Till_Next_Measure

FROM (Status AS s LEFT JOIN [Priotitization #2] AS p On s.Station_ID = p.Station_ID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
IIF(s.[Destroyed(yes/no)] = "no", s.Station_ID, "") AS Active_Stations, p.Days_Till_Next_Measure
FROM (Status AS s LEFT JOIN [Priotitization #2] AS p On s.Station_ID = p.Station_ID)
WHERE 1 = IIF(s.[Destroyed(yes/no)] = "no", 1, 2)
```

Does this work? I didn't try this cause I dont have Access.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `WHERE` clause to filter rows.  You can't filter rows in the `SELECT`.  So:

```
SELECT IIF(s.[Destroyed(yes/no)] = "no", s.Station_ID, "") AS Active_Stations,
      p.Days_Till_Next_Measure
FROM Status AS s LEFT JOIN
     [Priotitization #2] AS p
     On s.Station_ID = p.Station_ID
WHERE s.[Destroyed(yes/no)] = "no";
```